# How to correctly swap some characters in string

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string that represents a date:

```
"12.27.1995"
```

I need to swap the month and the day to get:

```
"27.12.1995"
```

I did:

```
date = "12.27.1995"

month = date[0]+date[1]
day = date[3]+date[4]

date[0] = day[0]
date[1] = day[1]
date[3] = month[0]
date[4] = month[1]
```

It works good, but looks to bad for me. Is it possible to make it more reliable using less code?

Comment: Using less code will not improve reliability. Instead, try to avoid fixed indices or check if the string matches the expected pattern before rearranging it that way. Maybe check if the string is actually a valid date when being interpreted as MM.DD.YYYY.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Perhaps like this:

```
date = "12.27.1995"
m, d, y = date.split(".")
date = [d, m, y].join(".")
```

Answer (score 7):

Since your string represents a date, you might want to use a [`Date`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) object, with [`strptime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) to parse the original string and [`strftime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime) to output it in the desired format:

```
require 'date'

date = Date.strptime("12.27.1995", "%m.%d.%Y")
puts date.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
# 27.12.1995
```

Answer (score 1):

While the answer by @sawa is perfectly valid and *should be used here*, I would show some technic which is *wrong and should not be used here*, but might be helpful for anybody to swap two fixed parts of the string:

```
"12.27.1995".tap { |s| s[0..1], s[3..4] = s[3..4], s[0..1] }
#⇒ "27.12.1995"
```

Answer (score 1):

Not elegant, but a way using regex captures:

```
/(\d{1,2})\.(\d{1,2})\.(\d{4})/.match "12.27.1995"
[$2, $1, $3].join('.') #=> "27.12.1995"
```

Comment: `"12.27.1995".sub(/(\d\d).(\d\d)/, '\2.\1')`